# I'm new to Ubuntu and I need to know how to install FL studio 12.03 step by step

Tags: wine, winetricks

hello I've tried to follow a couple of tutorials online but I'm just not getting anywhere. I have already installed all codecs and restricted extras. I know Wine is used but I'm not sure how to properly use it for what I need. FL studio is a Digital Audio Workstation.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32045 this software apparently works when using Wine. So the only thing you have to do is install Wine and then install FL studio using the installer.